# Convert JSON file to CSV with a Perl script

Tags: json, csv, perl

I try to convert a JSON file to CSV with a Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use JSON::MaybeXS;
use FileHandle ;
use IO::Handle;

local( $/, *FH ) ;

open( FH, '<', 'out_spot.json' ) or die "Can't open out_spot.json: $!";
my $text = <FH>;

my $data = decode_json($text);

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({auto_diag=>2,binary=>1, eol=>"\n", always_quote=>1 });

open(my $OUT, ">:encoding(utf8)", "out_spot.csv") or die "out_spot.csv: $!";
my @fields = qw/    spotterId   spotterName payloadType batteryVoltage  batteryPower    solarVoltage    humidity    track   latitude    longitude   timestamp   waves   significantWaveHeight   peakPeriod  meanPeriod  peakDirection   peakDirectionalSpread   meanDirection   meanDirectionalSpread   timestamp   latitude    longitude   frequencyData   frequency   df  varianceDensity direction   directionalSpread   timestamp   latitude    longitude /;
$csv->print($OUT, \@fields);
for my $datapoint ( @{ $data->{data} } ) {
   $csv->print($OUT, [ map {$datapoint->{$_}} @fields ]);
}

close $OUT;
```

The JSON file out_spot.json :

```
{
   "data" : {
       "spotterId" : "SPOT-30344R",
       "spotterName" : "",
       "payloadType" : "full",
       "batteryVoltage" : 4.01,
       "batteryPower" : -0.15,
       "solarVoltage" : 0.22,
       "humidity" : 46.4,
       "track" : [{
           "latitude" : -28.4223833,
           "longitude" : -37.5605,
           "timestamp" : "2023-09-12T06:28:31.000Z"
       }, {
           "latitude" : -28.4279833,
           "longitude" : -37.56795,
           "timestamp" : "2023-09-12T06:58:31.000Z"
       }],
    .....
}
```

The desire CSV output:

| spotterId | spotterName | payloadType | batteryVoltage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SPOT-30344R |  | full | 4.01 |

| latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- |
| -28.4223833 | -37.5605 |
| -28.4279833 | -37.56795 |

The script does not give me any errors, but the CSV file has no data, it only contains the header.

What it's wrong in my code ?

Comment: What have you done to debug this yourself? Do `$text` and `$data` contain what you expect?

Comment: There's no `Datapoints` in the JSON input.

Comment: I use : print Dumper $data;  and the output it's ok.  Yes, there's no Datapoints, it's "data"

Comment: `$data->{data}` isn't a reference to an array, so `@{ $data->{data} }` is wrong.

Comment: Re "*The desire CSV output:*", You followed this by *two* tables. But your code only opens one CSV file.

Comment: Yes, I want one CSV file, but here I can't create a table so big

Comment: "_Yes, I want one CSV file, but here I can't create a table so big_" -- so `lon` and `lat` fields continue the other four as one line of the header?  But, they have _two_ rows if values under them while the other four only have one row ...?  Then, your data continues (under `....`) -- what's up with that?  What kind of data continues? (Or is it irrelevant as you only need what you show?)  See, to me it is unclear what you have and what you need.  Also, why can't you just pluck needed headers and their values out of the data structure obtained when CSV is parsed? (How many rows of values?)

Comment: @tuxman: *but here I can't create a table so big* - then maybe just show us the CSV output that you expect, not a table of data.

Answer (score 3):

I've made your JSON sample more readable (you're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself in the future) and it becomes obvious that your JSON doesn't contain a `Datapoints` key, so I'm not sure why your code is expecting that.

Either your JSON sample isn't accurate, or your code doesn't match your input.

Further, it's not clear how your data maps onto a simple CSV file. You have multiple `track` records inside your `data` record. Perhaps you could edit your question to add the expected output from your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you started:

```
    use strict;
    use 5.010;
    use JSON::PP;

    our $hdr= 'spotterId,spotterName,payloadType,batteryVoltage,batteryPower,solarVoltage,humidity,latitude,longitude';
    our $q = '"';

    my $data = qx/cat data.json/;
    my $decoded_json = decode_json $data;

    my $o1 = $decoded_json->{data}->{spotterId};
    my $o2 = $decoded_json->{data}->{spotterName};
    my $o3 = $decoded_json->{data}->{payloadType};
    my $o4 = $decoded_json->{data}->{batteryVoltage};
    my $o5 = $decoded_json->{data}->{solarVoltage};
    my $o6 = $decoded_json->{data}->{humidity};

    my @track= ();
    my $track = ($decoded_json->{data}->{track});
    if ($track) {
      @track= @{$track};
    }

    my @lat=();
    my @lng=();
    foreach (@track) {
      push(@lat,$_->{latitude});
      push(@lng,$_->{longitude});
    }
    my $o7 = join ":", @lat; # change to newline I preferred colon
    my $o8 = join ":", @lng;

    say $hdr;
    say "$q$o1$q,$q$o2$q,$q$o3$q$o4$q,$q$o5$q,$q$o6$q,$q$o7$q,$q$o8$q";
```